# WP_Query($args) не работает вывод рекомендуемых

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
$meta_query[] = array(
                    'key'   => '_featured',
                    'value' => 'yes'
                );
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'posts_per_page' => 20,
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'meta_query'  =>  $meta_query,
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                );
```

Comment: при выводе через шорткод <?php echo do_shortcode( '[featured_products per_page="12" columns="4"]' ); ?> Работает. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

```
'post_type' => 'product',
                    'posts_per_page' => 5,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
                                'field'    => 'name',
                                'terms'    => 'featured',
                            ),
                        ),
                    );
```